# Handle a virus infection by Trojan-Spy.Win32.ZBot.a

Tags: windows, virus, malware, virus-removal, kaspersky

Since a couple of days I have a prompt from my KIS 2016 saying that he found this Trojan in MEM. I try to clean and restart the PC, all goes well, but in a while this message appears again. I have tried to download the ZBotKiller from Kaspersky website but it does not find anything (maybe because my antivirus has already cleaned the object). My question is, how can I understand in which way it infects and background runs again? I logically wish to solve this problem from the source! Maybe I have an open port in my firewall? I am not a newbie and I have never had this kind of problem.

P.S. Computer performances are excellent and I do not notice anything strange in behavior (like ads, popups, etc.). My main concern regards sensible data stored in my PC.

P.P.S. I do not click on spam or phishing mails nor I have downloaded anything strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What is the infection mechanism of Trojan-Spy.Win32.ZBot.a?

- Users clicking on links in emails that go to infected web pages ([social engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_%28security%29)).
- Users browsing an infected website ([drive-by download](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by_download)).

---

#### Technical details

> **PREVENTION AND AVOIDANCE**
>
> The following actions can be taken to avoid or minimize the risk from this threat.
>
> **User behavior and precautions**
>
> Trojan.Zbot relies heavily on social engineering in order to infect computers. The spam email campaigns
>   used by attackers attempt to trick the user by referencing the latest
>   news stories, playing upon fears their sensitive information has been
>   stolen, suggesting that compromising photos have been taken of them,
>   or any number of other ruses.
>
> Users should use caution when clicking links in such emails. Basic
>   checks such as hovering with the mouse pointer over each link will
>   normally show where the link leads to. Users can also check online Web
>   site rating services such as safeweb.norton.com to see if the site is
>   deemed safe to visit.
>
> **Patch operating system and software**
>
> The attackers behind this threat have been known to utilize exploit
>   packs in order to craft Web pages to exploit vulnerable computers and
>   infect them with Trojan.Zbot.
>
> As of February 24, 2010, Trojan.Zbot has been seen using the following
>   vulnerabilities:
>
> - AOL Radio AmpX ActiveX Control 'ConvertFile()' Buffer Overflow Vulnerability (BID 35028)
> - Microsoft Active Template Library Header Data Remote Code Execution Vulnerability (BID 35558)
> - Microsoft Internet Explorer ADODB.Stream Object File Installation Weakness (BID 10514)
> - Snapshot Viewer for Microsoft Access ActiveX Control Arbitrary File Download Vulnerability (BID 30114)
> - Adobe Reader 'util.printf()' JavaScript Function Stack Buffer Overflow Vulnerability (BID 30035)
> - Adobe Acrobat and Reader Collab 'getIcon()' JavaScript Method Remote Code Execution Vulnerability (BID 34169)
> - Adobe Reader and Acrobat (CVE-2009-2994) U3D 'CLODMeshDeclaration' Buffer Overflow Vulnerability (BID 36689)
> - Adobe Acrobat and Reader Multiple Arbitrary Code Execution and Security Vulnerabilities (BID 27641)
>
> Users are advised to ensure that their operating systems and any
>   installed software are fully patched, and that antivirus and firewall
>   software is up to date and operational. Users should turn on automatic
>   updates if available, so that their computers can receive the latest
>   patches and updates when they are made available.

...

> **INFECTION METHOD**
>
> This threat is known to infect computers through a number of methods.
>   We will examine each of these methods in more detail.
>
> **Spam emails**
>
> The attackers behind Trojan.Zbot have made a concerted effort to
>   spread their threat using spam campaigns. The subject material varies
>   from one campaign to the next, but often focuses on current events or
>   attempt to trick the user with emails purported to come from
>   well-known institutions such as FDIC, IRS, MySpace, Facebook, or
>   Microsoft.
>
> **Drive-by downloads**
>
> The authors behind Trojan.Zbot have also been witnessed using exploit
>   packs to spread the threat via drive-by download attacks. When an
>   unsuspecting user visits one of these Web sites, a vulnerable computer
>   will become infected with the threat.
>
> The particular exploits used to spread the threat vary, largely
>   depending on the proliferation and ease-of-use of exploits available
>   in the wild at the time the Trojan is distributed.
>
> As of February 24, 2010, Trojan.Zbot has been seen using the following
>   vulnerabilities:
>
> - AOL Radio AmpX ActiveX Control 'ConvertFile()' Buffer Overflow Vulnerability (BID 35028)
> - Microsoft Active Template Library Header Data Remote Code Execution Vulnerability (BID 35558)
> - Microsoft Internet Explorer ADODB.Stream Object File Installation Weakness (BID 10514)
> - Snapshot Viewer for Microsoft Access ActiveX Control Arbitrary File Download Vulnerability (BID 30114)
> - Adobe Reader 'util.printf()' JavaScript Function Stack Buffer Overflow Vulnerability (BID 30035)
> - Adobe Acrobat and Reader Collab 'getIcon()' JavaScript Method Remote Code Execution Vulnerability (BID 34169)
> - Adobe Reader and Acrobat (CVE-2009-2994) U3D 'CLODMeshDeclaration' Buffer Overflow Vulnerability (BID 36689)
> - Adobe Acrobat and Reader Multiple Arbitrary Code Execution and Security Vulnerabilities (BID 27641)

Source [Trojan.Zbot Technical Details](http://www.symantec.com/security_response/writeup.jsp?docid=2010-011016-3514-99&tabid=2)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I receive tons of spam but I never click on them or, worse, download something from those links either!

Comment: @LeonardoUrbano It also could be an infected website. See updated answer.

Comment: I saw.. I use my PC only to write C++/MQL codes and to surf on (always) the same websites to get soccer news.. No more! Furthermore I have always had an antivirus in my PC (I am loyal to KIS due to quality and performance it has) and so I cannot figure out how it is possible. For these reasons I wrote to have a more "raw" way to check if there is something really strange in my PC behavior.

Comment: It doesn't really matter how you got infected. Check [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/q/100360) for other ways to cleanup your PC if it keeps coming back.

Comment: I did.. Mine was curiosity on why it keeps me prompting to clean something that was already cleaned. I read what that guy argued saying that it is impossible to clean an infection up completely, and I wanted to have a more technical answer if possible. :)

Comment: <shrug> I answered as best as I was able to ...

Comment: Do not misunderstand me! Your answer was very exhaustive and I really appreciate your explanations! I expressed badly myself while formulating main question, it is my fault!